# cant save changes on access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, save

I have some code that uses an access file to store data :P

I wrote some data on the access file without code so I could read it, and the methods that read **work fine, like this one:**

```
class dbConection
{
private static OleDbConnection conection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\teacher assistant.mdb");
private static OleDbCommand comand = new OleDbCommand();
private static OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

public static bool canConnect()
    {
        try
        {
            conection.Open();

            if (conection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("conexion exitosa");
                conection.Close();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("conexion fallida");
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "conexion fallida, error: "+ex.Message );
            return false;
        }

    //more methods...

    }
```

and this one

```
    internal static Grupo[] GruposAsociadosCon(int idUsuario)
    {
        conection.Open();
        comand.Connection = conection;
        comand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Salones WHERE maestro=" + idUsuario.ToString();
        OleDbDataReader reader = null;
        reader = comand.ExecuteReader();

        List<Grupo> lGrupos = new List<Grupo>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt16(reader["idSalon"].ToString());
            int grado = Convert.ToInt16(reader["grado"].ToString());
            char grupo = reader["grupo"].ToString().First();
            string escuela = reader["escuela"].ToString();
            Grupo g = new Grupo(id, grado, grupo, escuela);

            lGrupos.Add(g);
        }

        reader.Close();
        conection.Close();

        return lGrupos.ToArray();

    }
```

the **problem** is with the methods that write data, like this one:

```
   internal static bool RegistrarUsuario(string usuario, string contra)
    {
        conection.Open();
        comand.Connection = conection;
        comand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE usuario='" + usuario + "'" ;
        OleDbDataReader reader = comand.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show( "EL usuario ya existe" );
            conection.Close();
            throw new Exception("Ya existe este usuario");
        }

        reader.Close();
        comand = new OleDbCommand();
        comand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Usuarios (usuario, contrasena) VALUES('"+usuario+"', '"+contra+"')";
        comand.Connection = conection;
        Console.WriteLine(comand.ExecuteNonQuery()+" lienas con cambios");
        conection.Close();
        return true;
    }
```

when I store the data on the file it does not apear on the accessFile, I dont get an exception, the program works as if the data was there,

> ```
> comand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE usuario='" + usuario + "'" ;
> OleDbDataReader reader = comand.ExecuteReader();
> if (reader.HasRows)
> {
> ```
>
> reader.HasRows retuns true

it works like if the data was there until I close the program, it seems to me that it is creating a temporal file or something and it does not save changes when closing.
how can I make the changes permanent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I can see in the code you have posted the changes should be permanent.  One thing I would like to point out is that your code that is creating the INSERT statement is vulnerable to SQL Injection Attack.  You can research what this is and find out if it applies to you (basically it all depends on if Access supports SQL commands like DROP TABLE and so on.

A number of things I would check.

1. Find the MDB file in your solution and check its properties.  One of the properties will be "Copy To Output Directory" and this needs to be set to Copy If Newer rather than Copy Always.  When you set the value to Copy Always then each time you run the program the empty copy of your MDB file is overwriting the MDB that has data in it in your DEBUG/RELEASE folder.  The Copy if Newer will only replace the data file if you make changes to the structure of the MDB thus making its date newer than the one in your debug folder.
2. If the above is not the issue, then you might have a corrupt MDB and you need to open it in Access and run a repair on it.

Comment: The other issue that I found during my research is your connection string.  debug your code line by line and see what .NET is turning |DataDirectory| into.  I theory it should be the directory in which the code is being run (same  as the EXE).  Even if you have enabled ClickOnce deployment, during DEBUG, it should still resolve to the data folder.  If none of that provides any illumination, I would be interested in looking at the whole source package to see if I can trace the error, however, there may be privacy and code ownership issues that may prevent that kind of help.

Comment: The reason I go for the connection string here is because your code is obviously saving the data, that much is clear.. so the question to answer is.. where is the data going?  If you cannot resolve the location being given (aka .NET does not tell you), then I suggest using a fully qualified path to an MDB file that is not under the control of .NET (outside the debug folder)... e.g   c:\temp\teacher assistant.mdb.  The last thing I would do is to create an MDB without spaces in the filename.  I know your supposed to be able to use spaces etc.  but just for shiggles and gits....   :-)

Comment: thanks, that was it, i changed the MDB to "Copy If Newer", and changed the conection string to just the anme o the DB "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=teacher assistant.mdb"